# Стандарты PSR PHP

Tags: php

Я пишу небольшой PHP скрипт, который желательно сделать одним файлом. При этом стараюсь соблюдать стандарты PSR, в одном из них говориться:

> Код, написанный для PHP 5.3 и более новых версий, ДОЛЖЕН использовать формальные пространства имён

По факту у меня всего 2 класса, использовать пространство в этой ситуации не очень удобно. Если я нарушу этот стандарт в данной ситуации, будет ли это расценено экспертами как ошибка?

Comment: Почему для вас важно мнение экспертов? Вы разрабатываете скрипт, который будете выкладывать в открытый доступ? Планируете прикладывать в "портфолио"?

Comment: *По факту у меня всего 2 класса, использовать пространство в этой ситуации не очень удобно.* - речь об одной строчке кода. Точно неудобно?

Comment: Речь идет о cli-приложении, по определенной причине оно должно быть написано на php. В Linux должно запускаться определенной командой, скорее всего использую bash-алиасы. И да, возможно оно попадет в открытый доступ.

Comment: в cli скрипте, который планируется использовать автономно (без использования в виде библиотеки) вы можете (и должны) положить на это требование, иначе вы начнете каждую вторую строчку в свой неймспейс упаковывать, а если скрипт планируется использовать в виде библиотеки, вы написали скрипт неправильно и библиотеку неправильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> При этом стараюсь соблюдать стандарты PSR

Определись, зачем ты это делаешь.

Речь, видимо, идет о PSR-1. 
И тут нужно отдавать отчет, что этот стандарт был принят для того, чтобы код было легче понимать, повторно использовать и определять автора. Т.е., так или иначе, для коллективной работы над кодом.

Если ты не собираешься ни с кем делиться, то можешь не объявлять пространство имен.

Но если ты хочешь его где-то выложить, или же просто набить привычку - то следуй стандартам, и привыкни вставлять namespace.
Одна строчка `namespace \Fmustang\ToyProject;` не требует усилий (тем более, можно настроить IDE, чтобы он делал это автоматически), но вроде как приучает к хорошему тону.

Answer (score 2):

Да конечно.Это глубочайшее нарушение общепринятых условий.Следовать стандартам это означает 1)дисциплина,2) организованный код по правилам которые соблюдают другие,3)Ваш код пригоден для использования на ряду с другими по этому стандарту,4) Облегчает жизнь при работе в команде и. т. д.

> Да может быть он работает.Да может быть это классный код.Но его трудно поддерживать при мере разрастания.Каждый раз придется лезть в него чтобы понять где что лежит.И скорее всего в дальнейшем вы сами откажитесь от него.

Представь себе ситуацию.Вы и 3-4 человеко собираете машины.Они по стандартам (руль спереди,педали под ногами,и. т. д).И вы,так как взбрело в вашу голову.
Подходят покупатели и начинают естественно спрашивать вас - А где руль,педали ... ? Вы - Да вон там и там.
Догадайся с 3 раз чьей машиной они будут пользоваться :)
Не будьте криворуким программистом у которых лозунг один - Нет ничего такого чистого и светлого что нельзя испохабить руками.

Изначально будете испытывать дискомфорт,это естественно.И помните что эти стандарты придумывают не глупы люди.У которых наверняка опыта и знаний больше.

**Так что мой совет**  Пользоваться стандартами которые изобрели умные люди это правильней.Надеюсь помог.Удачи

[PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Answer (score 0):

Любой стандарт -- не более чем рекомендация. Нарушать ее или следовать, решать лично Вам. Особенно, если дело касается личных проектов. Например в фреймворке Yii [есть один класс](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii.html) без пространства имен (в глобальном пространстве). И ничего, все живет, дышит и пользуется популярностью.

В данной ситуации можно поступить так: классам выдать пространство имен и создать еще один файл, который будет использовать эти классы. А потом все это дело [упаковать в исполняемый phar файл](https://github.com/box-project/box2).